# Laravel: append category name to returned object

Tags: php, laravel

I am not sure if I'm on the right track here. In database `songs` I store `genre_id` as integer, and in `genres` table I have ID and name for the genre.

When returning a song from this `findBySlug` function, I want to include the genre name in my `$song` object.

```
public function findBySlugOrFail($slug)
    {
        $song = $this->song->whereSlug($slug)->first();
        $genre = Genre::where('id', $song->genre_id)->first();
        $genreName = $genre->name; // returns string "Rock"

        return $song;
    }
```

For now, `$song` returns this:

```
{
  "id":1,
  "user_id":1,
  "genre_id":1,
  "artist":"U2",
  "title":"Beautiful Day",
  "slug":"beautiful-day"
}
```

Is there a way to get the `$genreName` to be appended to the `$song` object? Or is there a better way to have the category name be exposed in this object?

Comment: Do you have a `belongsTo(Genre::class)` relationship defined on your `Song` model? If not, I recommend you define it.

Comment: Yes I do have this defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a ton of ways to do this.

Most common:

```
public function findBySlugOrFail($slug)
{
    $song = $this->song->whereSlug($slug)->with('genre')->first();
    return $song;
}
```

But the object will be a bit different. It will have the whole `genre` object appended to it.

Easiest for this case:

```
public function findBySlugOrFail($slug)
{
    $song = $this->song->whereSlug($slug)->first();
    $song->genre_name = $song->genre()->first()->name;
    return $song;
}
```

You could also define [an accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) called `getGenreNameAttribute()` on the `Song` model.

Or you could create an [Eloquent resource](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-resources) and define exactly how the object will be returned. This one is probably the best practice for an API

Comment: Why not return the whole object, I can easily work with that. Thanks, it was easier than I thought!